# Why does an augmented matrix with bottom-right 1 represent a system without solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

To determine whether a system of linear equations lacks a solution, we can convert it into reduced row echelon form. If the bottom-right value is 1, then the system lacks solutions.

Why is this true? It just seems like a random indicator to me.

Comment: Hint: How can zero times anything equal 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong here. The matrix $$\pmatrix{1&0&1\cr0&1&1\cr}$$ is in reduced row-echelon form, the bottom-right entry is $1$, and the system represented by the matrix does not lack solutions. What do you really mean?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that you're right. Perhaps what I said is not true then...

Comment: Oh wait, but it is true if the bottom row in reduced echelon form is all 0s except for the rightmost term (which is 1). Thanks!